# Issue with DevExpress XtraTabControl

Tags: foreach, devexpress, tabcontrol

I am having a DevExpress XtraTabControl with 3 XtraTabPages.
I am trying to remove a Tabpage based on a condition and after removing for the last iteration,it is getting error.

My Code is

```
foreach (DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage ptp in tabContactsDetails.TabPages)
            {
                if (tabContactsDetails.TabPages.Contains(ptp))
                {
                    if (ptp.Name == "tabPTP")
                    {
                        if (maxid == String.Empty || maxid == null || maxid == "lblHiddenDebtorID")
                        {
                            tabContactsDetails.TabPages.Remove(ptp);                                
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and I am getting an error like

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a collection while iterating through it!

What I do is the following:

```
List<XtraTabPage> tabPagesToBeRemoved = new List<XtraTabPage>();

foreach (XtraTabPage ptp in tabContactsDetails.TabPages)
{
    if (shouldBeRemoved())
    {
        tabPagesToBeRemoved.Add(ptp);
    }
}

foreach (XtraTabPage pageToBeRemoved in tabPagesToBeRemoved)
{
    tabContactsDetails.TabPages.Remove(pageToBeRemoved);
}
```